# UIView categories and drop shadow -- being applied twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, categories, objective-c-category

I've created a category on UIView that allows me to add a drop shadow to the view.  My code for the shadow looks like this:

```
-(void)addDropShadowWithOffset:(CGFloat)offset {
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, offset);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}
```

It works great.  However, I've noticed that when I rotate the screen the shadow gets redrawn.  The more I rotate it, the more the shadow is redrawn, leading to a shadow much larger than I originally wanted.

I originally thought about adding a BOOL iVar to the category that would let me track whether or not the shadow has already been drawn.  But, it appears as though I can't add iVars to a category.  So, how can I prevent this code from being run more than once per UIView?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you call it from method that is calling for every screen rotation (for example - layoutSubview) right?
Method `drawRect:` and `layoutSubviews` are calling every time when you rotate the screen.

Move your method call to `awakeFromNib` method and should work fine.

**EDIT:**

Like you set in comment, if you building your interface from code, and using `layoutSubviews` to call shadow you may check if shadow is loaded with no additional bool flag. Just check:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if(!self.layer.shadowPath) {
        [self addDropShadowWithOffset:1.0];
    }
}
```

But, if you change size for example with rotation you may want to redraw the shadow after it. If you want to do this, just use the same mechanism as above.

**EDIT2**

Here is an idea. Maybe if you want to draw it only once you should override the initialiser. This is one-time call method.

Comment: You are correct.  I am calling this in layoutSubviews.  However, I am drawing UIView in code, rather than through a NIB.  Any other workaround?  I obviously want the shadow to be applied properly when rotating, but that is not what is currently happening.